# How to encode/decode Arabic in JSON String in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, unicode, urlencode

I want to first encode a JSON String (it has some **Arabic words**) and then decode it in my JavaScript file.

PS: This piece of code works fine if the JSON String has only English Words. 
But I want it to work for **Arabic Words** also.

Encoding:

```
<input type="hidden" id="cei-nav-urlparam-ceiIndex" value='<%= URLEncoder.encode(ceiIndexTree, "UTF-8") %>' />
```

Decoding:

```
   this.initFiltersValues = function(ceinavUrlPara) {
    ceinavUrlParams = unescape(ceinavUrlPara);
    ceinavUrlParams = ceinavUrlParams.replace(/\+/g, " ");
    var res = $.parseJSON(ceinavUrlParams);
    console.log('INITIAL FILTER FROM URL: '+ceinavUrlParams);
    return res;
   };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using UTF-8 solves the purpose instead of ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 2):

**The right way**

You are inserting data into an HTML document, not a URL. Use [`org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils escapeHtml()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml%28java.io.Writer,%20java.lang.String%29) or another HTML encoding function.

Then you don't need to do anything to decode it to a JSON string — the browser will do that. Just go directly to `parseJSON`.

**Fixing your way**

See [the manual for `unescape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_functions) where it says:

> The escape and unescape functions do not work properly for non-ASCII characters and have been deprecated. In JavaScript 1.5 and later, use encodeURI, decodeURI, encodeURIComponent, and decodeURIComponent.

Comment: `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils escapeHtml()`
Used this code but it was of no help.

Comment: @rahulkgupta — Did you remember to remove the `unescape` and the `+` regex?

Comment: Then it should work fine. Possibly the problem lies elsewhere (such as in the data you are encoding in the first place).

Comment: I am trying to encode this JSON String.
`{"filtervalues": {"servicetab": [{"logicalOperator": "AND","operatorType": "Equal","operands": ["أشتراك سنوي -خدمة بس تن(AGB1)"]}]}}`

Used this for Encoding: `<input type="hidden" id="currentFilters" value='<%= org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(currentFilters) %>' />`

Used this for Decoding: `this.getValues = function() {
  var ceinavUrlParams = jQuery('#currentFilters').val();
  var res = $.parseJSON(ceinavUrlParams);
  return res;
 };`

Comment: can you use firebug to check out the server response? there must be some kind of "Content-Encoding: utf-8" in the http response header. if not than the browser cannot interpret the arabic strings correctly.

Answer (score 0):

how does your page get the data? via ajax-request or via an plain submit? without knowing this i just can just give you an common advice. make your page an utf8 page. with this the browser will handle the conversion. in my project i had no problems displaying russian or chinese characters after doing this. the browser did the work. i just had to tell him that i am using utf-8 data.

so add this to your html page:

```
<title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</title>
```

and this to your html-forms:

```
<form name="xxx" id="yyy" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="POST" >
```

and use this to make your ajax requests utf-8 compatible:

```
setRequestHeader("content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
```

this helped in my case. I also had to "manually" set the server response (for ajax requests) to utf-8. I had to change the http headers "Content-Encoding"="utf-8". how you can achieve this depends on your solution. in my case i had to do it this way. in jsp or php there might be other ways to do this.

Comment: UTF-8 charset is the problem. With UTF-8, English is working but Arabic words are not getting encoded properly.

Comment: the utf-8 string may be broken. i had the problem that my database delivered some utf-8 strings. but my cgi-script interpreted them as "normal" strings. therfore an "ü" was converted to an "Ã¼". try to find the point where the encoding goes wrong. are the strings properly encoded in your database?

Comment: How can i check that whether encoding is not working? 
I am passing the encoded data to another page via form submit.
Same thing works for English words.

Comment: so in your form you have correct encoded arabic chars? an than you submit these chars to an other page. in the other page the character are broken? try to add "accept-charset="UTF-8"" to your form which contains the arabic characters. then check out if the other page is an utf-8 page.